# EJB commit on web service timeout

Tags: web-services, glassfish, timeout, ejb

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2. I have an application that has an EJB (called MyBean) with TransactionManagementType.BEAN set on class level. In a business method I get connection from data source, set auto commit to false on the connection, do INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE on database tables and than commit at the end. Then I have a web service (called MyWebService) implemented in seperate class, that uses MyBean to call business methods. The client application is a seperate Java application that has webservice client generated with WSDL of MyWebService. The client has set a timeout to 10 seconds. If the call to MyWebService takes more than 10 seconds the client gets a timout exception. This all OK. The problem I have is that in the Glassfish log I see that MyBean did all the work and also commited changed, but I don't see data in the database.
This is driving me crazy! Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out that web service, Java EE or even GlassFish is not the guilty party.
The guilty party is the client, that also does some updates on the database. The client was responsible to overwrite the expected results.